# want my phone off, when charging

Tags: lumia-950

Windows 10 phone will not turn off while charging, very annoying.
Powered phone off while charging it comes back on again, will not stop coming on again and I want it off but plugged in to charge, don't want to be forced to have phone on al night long for a change

Answer (score 3):

**Unfortunately, you're out of luck.** That has been a sore point -- for many people -- for years. Even if you ran it all the way down to where it forcefully shut itself off, it would restart as soon as it had enough juice to do so.

You've got a couple of options to mimic the off state:

- Put it in Airplane Mode at night.
- Turn on Quiet Hours, remove all VIPs and uncheck the option to "breakthrough if called 3 times".

Of course this isn't the same thing as "off", but it's as close as you're going to get with all Windows mobile devices since Windows Phone 8.

I wouldn't worry about it, however. Yes, it will minutely shorten the overall lifespan of the battery and device. I don't have hard data to prove that, but all things break down with continual use... including the 950. However, my wife's is still going strong after nearly 4 years of use, and she abuses the heck out of that battery. My own 950XL still works fine too, and until I switched platforms (about two years ago) it was NEVER turned off.

Answer (score -1):

Long press on your power button to turn your phone off